# How to use ShedLock in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration, shedlock, distributed-lock

I am combining the Spring Batch and Spring Integration, I am using the poller with a corn:

```
@Bean
@SchedulerLock(name = "importEntitiesRiskCodes", lockAtMostForString = "PT5M")
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource(),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.cron("0-7 1-59/5 * * * ?").maxMessagesPerPoll(maxFilesPerPoll)))
            .channel(fileIn())
            .transform(fileMessageToJobrequest())
            .handle(jobLaunchingGateway())
            .log()
            .get();
}
```

I know that Spring Integration JDBC provides `JDBCLockRepository` but I want to know how to use the ShedLock.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your description how you are going to use that lock at all, but according to this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring), it doesn't look like there is anything related to Spring Integration.

On the other hand, even if I'm not familiar with library, it doesn't look bad to add a `LockRegistry` implementation for ShedLock into Spring Integration. Although it might not be relevant to your task...

Comment: Greetings Artem, first of all, thanks.  I've edited my question. Yes, I can use it as the example suggested but the problem is I want to take advantage of the Poller that Spring Integration offers and combine it with Shedlock.

Comment: Well, what you show does not make sense . That annotation is not going to do anything valuable at run time.  You probably need to think about custom `Trigger` implementation instead of cron.

Comment: Yeah that exactly what I did. Thanks my point was to know if there is out a box this integration.

Comment: well out of the box is the JdbcLockRegistry